# Diferencia entre error léxico y sintáctico

Tags: c++

es la primera vez que hablo en el foro.
Me gustaría que alguien me explicase, por favor, la diferencia entre error léxico y sintáctico y como la primera puede influir en la segunda.

Me explico con un ejemplo:

wh?ile: error léxico y sintáctico.

¿while: solo error léxico.

La definición de ambos errores las sé, lo que me gustaría entender es el por qué.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

El léxico es lo que escribes. Un error léxico es escribir mal:

> ola ke ase

- El saludo ["*hola*"](https://dle.rae.es/hola) se escribe con hache, [sin hache](https://dle.rae.es/ola) es una *Onda de gran amplitud que se forma en la superficie de las aguas*.
- El pronombre relativo ["*que*"](https://dle.rae.es/que) se escribe con cu y u.
- La segunda persona del presente de indicativo del verbo ["*hacer*"](https://dle.rae.es/hacer#conjugacionfIOsOqS) se escribe "*haces*".

---

La sintaxis es cómo escribes. Un error sintáctico es no seguir las normas de escritura:

> yo ser jefe tribu

- La primera palabra de una frase debe escribirse con la inicial en mayúscula.
- Los verbos en infinitivo deben ir acompañados de un verbo conjugado pero en esta frase se esperaba la primera persona del presente de indicativo.
- La palabra jefe debe ir acompañada de un artículo.
- La palabra tribu debe ir acompañada de un artículo y unirse al resto de la frase con una preposición.

---

Un error es léxico y a la vez sintáctico cuando escribes mal y además no sigues las normas de escritura.